How can I nest Jsonnet object comprehensions and run the inner loop a different number of times?
I'm trying to figure out how to nest/chain an object comprehension to do something other than a 'full product' and have the inner loop iterate a different amount, but can't figure it out.
{
    ["%s-thing-%i" % [grp.name, n]]: {
        name: grp.name,
        // a bunch of other stuff I don't want to repeat
    }
    // for n in std.range(1, grp.count)  // invalid, 'Unknown variable: grp'
    for n in std.range(1, 3)
    for grp
    in [{name: "foo", count: 2}, {name: "bar", count: 4}]
}

I want a one-level object with two foo-thing-s and four bar-thing-s, but I can't use the count object property like on my commented line as at that point grp is not defined.

Below snippet seems to implement what you need, without the flatMap() transform "in the middle":
source
local input = [{ name: 'foo', count: 2 }, { name: 'bar', count: 4 }];
{
  ['%s-thing-%i' % [entry.name, n]]: { name: entry.name }
  for entry in input
  for n in std.range(1, entry.count)
}

output
{
   "bar-thing-1": {
      "name": "bar"
   },
   "bar-thing-2": {
      "name": "bar"
   },
   "bar-thing-3": {
      "name": "bar"
   },
   "bar-thing-4": {
      "name": "bar"
   },
   "foo-thing-1": {
      "name": "foo"
   },
   "foo-thing-2": {
      "name": "foo"
   }
}


You can do the expansion on the array fed into the object comprehension first. Use the std.flatMap stdlib function to generate objects with a unique n:
{
    ["%s-thing-%i" % [grp.name, grp.n]]: {
        name: grp.name,
    }
    for grp
    in std.flatMap(
        function(x) [
            x + {n: n}  // adding here so the full object is available
            for n
            in std.range(1, x.count)
        ],
        [{name: "foo", count: 2}, {name: "bar", count: 4}]
    )
}

Output:
{
   "bar-thing-1": {
      "name": "bar"
   },
   "bar-thing-2": {
      "name": "bar"
   },
   "bar-thing-3": {
      "name": "bar"
   },
   "bar-thing-4": {
      "name": "bar"
   },
   "foo-thing-1": {
      "name": "foo"
   },
   "foo-thing-2": {
      "name": "foo"
   }
}

